# How to enable core dump on Fedora 16?

Tags: fedora-16

**My configuration.**

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
core
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pipe_limit 
0
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid 
1
$ selinuxenabled && echo enabled || echo disabled
disabled
$ ps aux | grep abrt
500       2192  0.0  0.1 251036  5640 ?        S    10:01   0:00 abrt-applet
500       5673  0.0  0.0 109252   884 pts/0    S+   10:29   0:00 grep --color=auto abrt
$ ulimit -c
unlimited
```

**What I do.**

I start my program in a gnome-terminal with bash. It doesn't get daemonized or detached.
Then I do the following from another terminal `killall -ABRT <program_name>`. The program ends leaving message `Aborted`. No core file can be found on filesystem.

How this situation can be helped? What else can I do or check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is found.

The problem was with core_pattern, since my program somehow changed it's cwd to `/` and, thus, can't write anything to filesystem root.

Process cwd can be seen under `/proc/<pid>/cwd`.

So, I changed core_pattern with `echo '/tmp/core.%p' > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` and it helped.